# How should I use route&view

Tags: backbone.js

Background:
I am using backbone.js & Twitter Bootstrap in my client-end page.

On clicking the logout button on header, a confirmation dialog should open.

The question is that

1. should I use router such as /logout to change to logoutView ?
2. If click No in the dialog, how could I show the main content with data before the dialog is opened.

Thanks!

Comment: Use this method to hide the modal temporarily. Modal will not be removed from the DOM and will be reused.

Comment: Please see the update and the video I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use router for such thing. Just fire the modal directly because:

1. On changing the router, you are gonna push that to the `History`. Hitting the browser's back button shouldn't really open a modal window.
2. URLs should be crafted in a way to be bookmarked. You don't want a URL that would open a popup or a modal window!
3. It's much simpler just to start the modal than to create a variable to hold the previous view and to fall back to it when clicking **No**

I have build client-side apps using different MVC frameworks like AngularJS and Backbone.js. Every time I faced the same situation you are talking about and found that the easiest and most accurate way is to just show the modal.

**UPDATE**

Please [watch this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4udR30JYenA#t=2441s). This is Jeremy Ashkenas the author of backbone.js stating exactly your situation about how should URLs be used and weather if they should be used to open a pop up or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a router and you should.

First thing to know, is you have to render application's layout before dispatching any route, because the layout is rendered and needed for every action, so it's independant, right ?

Second you create a "logout" route in your router and give it the "#logout" hash, then in your "logout" action you open the modal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But after close the dialog, The main page will rerender without the data it had kept.

Comment: "The main page will rerender without the data it had kept." What do you mean ? If you close the modal you should redirect to the homepage (`<a href="#">close modal</a>`)